# Pyspark ML - prediction value of RandomForestClassificationModel

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I've tried [random_forest_classifier_example.py](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-2.3/examples/src/main/python/ml/random_forest_classifier_example.py), and it works. For the next step, I've tried prediction using 3rd row of [sample_libsvm_data.txt](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-2.3/data/mllib/sample_libsvm_data.txt), which has label "1". I've added:

```
indexes = [
    124, 125, 126, 127, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155, 179,
    180, 181, 182, 183, 208, 209, 210, 211, 235, 236,
    237, 238, 239, 263, 264, 265, 266, 267, 268, 292,
    293, 294, 295, 296, 321, 322, 323, 324, 349, 350,
    351, 352, 377, 378, 379, 380, 405, 406, 407, 408,
    433, 434, 435, 436, 461, 462, 463, 464, 489, 490,
    491, 492, 493, 517, 518, 519, 520, 521, 545, 546,
    547, 548, 549, 574, 575, 576, 577, 578, 602, 603,
    604, 605, 606, 630, 631, 632, 633, 634, 658, 659,
    660, 661, 662
]
values = [
    145.0, 255.0, 211.0, 31.0, 32.0, 237.0, 253.0, 252.0, 71.0, 11.0,
    175.0, 253.0, 252.0, 71.0, 144.0, 253.0, 252.0, 71.0, 16.0, 191.0,
    253.0, 252.0, 71.0, 26.0, 221.0, 253.0, 252.0, 124.0, 31.0, 125.0,
    253.0, 252.0, 252.0, 108.0, 253.0, 252.0, 252.0, 108.0, 255.0, 253.0,
    253.0, 108.0, 253.0, 252.0, 252.0, 108.0, 253.0, 252.0, 252.0, 108.0,
    253.0, 252.0, 252.0, 108.0, 255.0, 253.0, 253.0, 170.0, 253.0, 252.0,
    252.0, 252.0, 42.0, 149.0, 252.0, 252.0, 252.0, 144.0, 109.0, 252.0,
    252.0, 252.0, 144.0, 218.0, 253.0, 253.0, 255.0, 35.0, 175.0, 252.0,
    252.0, 253.0, 35.0, 73.0, 252.0, 252.0, 253.0, 35.0, 31.0, 211.0,
    252.0, 253.0, 35.0
]
testDf = spark.createDataFrame([(Vectors.sparse(692, indexes, values),)], ["indexedFeatures"])
result = rfModel.transform(testDf).head()
print(result.prediction)
```

just before

```
spark.stop()
```

of [random_forest_classifier_example.py](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-2.3/examples/src/main/python/ml/random_forest_classifier_example.py), then run the code. I've expected to get "result.prediction = 1.0", but obtained "result.prediction = 0.0". Do I misunderstand something? Does anyone have an idea?

I'm using pyspark 2.3, adding:

```
from pyspark.ml.linalg import Vectors
```

and I've referred "class RandomForestClassifier" portion of [classification.py](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-2.3/python/pyspark/ml/classification.py). Thank you.

Comment: _I've expected to get "result.prediction = 1.0", but obtained "result.prediction = 0.0"_ - why did you? Classifiers are not perfect and can provide both false positives and false negatives. There is no reason for a specific record to be correctly classified, even if it occurred in training dataset (unless of course data is trivial).

Comment: @user9613318 Thank you for comment. I've run the code many times, but got same result (result.prediction = 0.0), so that I think I've made mistake(s).

Comment: Spark `RandomForest` is mostly deterministic when operating on small data so it should converge to the same solution. Unless you you tuned algorithm with (significantly) different parameters each time, there is no reason to expect different results.

Comment: @user9613318 Thank you again. I've changed `predictions.select("predictedLabel", "label", "features").show(5)` to `....show(35, truncate=50)` in random_forest_classifier_example.py (around line 70), then wait for appearance of the corresponding data (3rd row of sample_libsvm_data.txt). It sometimes happens in several trials. In my observation, it's predictedLabel has "1.0" in most cases. But even in this timing, the "result.prediction" has "0.0". I think it's strange.